# Inserting Same Data Into Two Different Tables On Same Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

Ok so I have two different tables within the same model.edmx in an asp.net entity framework mvc project. The first table is the main table I have set up to update and have no trouble with it. The second table is an empty table that has exactly the same schema as the first. The second table will have the rows from table 1 inserted into it to log changes and who made the changes over time.

Is there any way I can take the data modeled for table 1 and convert it to be modeled for table 2 and just insert the row?

The error I get when attempting to reference table 1 from table 2 is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Model1' to 'Model2'".

Here is the ActionResult where I am attempting to do this:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,ECode,EmpType,FTE,TeamName,ReportGroup,Include,GoalEdDol,GoalEdAcct,GoalCmDol,GoalCmAcct,Update_By,Update_Date")] Staffing staffing)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            staffing.Update_Date = DateTime.Now;
            staffing.Update_By = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
            db.Entry(staffing).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();


            Staffing_Hist staffing_hist = staffing;
            // I would like to do similar to above but I have to convert staffing into a staffing_hist model

            return RedirectToAction("Index");    
        }
        return View(staffing);
    }
```

I am new to asp.net and entity framework. I've been teaching myself over the past few weeks so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use database triggers to do this instead?

Comment: Staffing_Hist and Staffing are considered 2 different types. [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) is great for these kinds of tasks. Code would look something like staffing_hist = Mapper.Map(staffing); Another option is to add a constructor to Staffing_Hist that takes a Staffing object and manually maps it.  var staffing_hist = new Staffing_Hist(staffing);

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will definitely give Automapper a try.

Comment: Automapper did the trick. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way.

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,namee,no")] tbl_in staffing)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            staffing.namee ="Test";
            staffing.no = 1235467890;
            db.Entry(staffing).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            tbl_out t = new tbl_out();
            t.id = staffing.id;
            t.namee = staffing.namee;
            t.no = staffing.no;
            db.tbl_out.Add(t);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        return View(staffing);
    }
```